# Java - How can I edit a class file

Tags: java

I have a self extracting exe file, if I open that file with 7-zip inside it I can see a bunch of java class files.

I need to make a simple change, if I open the class file in notepad, although it is a binary mess the change I need to make is an ascii value which is readbale in the text editor, if I edit the file, change it and update the archive, the application will no longer run. (Guess it sees the file as corrupted now)

How can I edit this file and put it back in the archive?
Can I decompile the single class file, recompile it and put it back into the archive?

Comment: *Can I decompile the single class file, recompile it and put it back into the archive?* Maybe. Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: why are you not changing the source instead so that you could recompile/repackage it? is it your own code (or code you are allowed to modify)?

Comment: _"if I edit the file, change it and update the archive, the application will no longer run."_  Your text editor is corrupting other non-ascii (binary) parts of the file. Your question is akin to _"How can I edit a .EXE file"_, and in both cases, judicious use of a Hex Editor is possible. But as others have commented - change the source and re-compile. De-compile from .class to source if you don't have the source.

Comment: If the change you want to make is to a non-binary member of the archive (i.e. a text file of some sort) you should be able to extract the entire contents of the archive to a temp location, modify the text file, and recreate a new version of the archive.  Maybe.  You'd need to know the mechanism that was used to pack the self-extractor with the archive, and sometimes that is proprietary.

Comment: I can decompile the file easily, however there are about 20 imports. So I suspect trying to recompile is going to be difficult. I am playing arounnd with a tool called "java Class Editor" however it seems out of the hundreds of class files in this folders this is the only one it cannot open :p

Comment: ":P" You just answered your own question? If that class editor doesnt work there are a few out there, Like the Eclipse Decompiler  https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-class-decompiler. etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay figured it out.

java Class editor is a small program they may work for basic files.

However I found this better way:

browse to the exe in 7-zip, right click and select "view inside"
Browse to the folder containing the class file.
Extract the class file to your pc.
Open the class file with "Dirty Joe Java overall Editor" make the changes you need and be sure to click file/save./ Copy the file back into 7-zip and you have a working exe with the modification you just made. No need to decompile!

Comment: How I can modified the source inside method?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. I think what you have to do is,

1) Extract the class files to somewhere.

2) Decompile everything.

3) Make your change.

4) Recompile all the java file.

5) Make a new self extracting archive.

*You can use a site like this to decompile
  http://www.javadecompilers.com/

Comment: recompile gives me error what to do